# Node module included in babel-loader is not defined in Webpack 5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babel-loader, webpack-5

I need to include a node_module (nanoid) in babel-loader in order to down transpile it to ES5.
This used to work in Webpack 4:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  module: {
    rules: [
       test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
       exclude: /node_modules\/(?!nanoid)/,
       loader: 'babel-loader',
    ],
  },
  ...
};
```

but since I updated to Webpack 5 I get this error in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
    at eval (index.js:7)
    at eval (index.js:8)
    at Module../node_modules/nanoid/url-alphabet/index.js (bundle.js:3489)
```

Webpack throws no error while compiling, but running the bundle in the browser throws the above-mentioned error.

Comment: Unable to replicate your issue. It appears to be working as [expected](https://i.imgur.com/cyUtWxf.png). Working demo can be found [here](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/react-start-kit-webpack5). This demo repo **SHOULD NEVER** be used for production; it was hacked together for experimental purposes. On that note, you should use `include` instead of `exclude`; for example: ```include: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](nanoid)[\\/]/```.

Comment: Did you actually import and used nanoid in your code?

Comment: [Yes](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/react-start-kit-webpack5/blob/master/src/pages/Home/index.js#L12), you can also run [checkbuild](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/react-start-kit-webpack5/blob/master/package.json#L16) to see if the production build is ES5 compliant.

Comment: @Less The example works, it's just hiding the compilation stats. In the `package.json` under `scripts`,  change `dev` to be:  `"dev": "NODE_ENV=development PORT=3000 webpack serve",` and it'll show the [output](https://i.imgur.com/NK9WGz1.png).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but only when using `--hot` with `webpack-dev-server`.

Unfortunately i could not find a fix for that but figured out that the problem seems to be with `exports` field in `package.json` of `nanoid` since version `3`.

It seems that some package, webpack?, webpack-dev-server?, others..?, involved in hot loading does not properly resolve the `exports` field.

I did a downgrade to version `2` of `nanoid` which is properly resolved and the error disappears.

Comment: Yeah I figured also that problem was somehow related to `nonoid`. Eventually I had to remove it and use another package.

Comment: you can use version 2 of nanoid